# Return ID of HTML Object

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

Currently I am using VBA and excel to automate some webpage functionality. I am able to export all the values I want using the .innerText function, but I wanted to know if was possible to return the html ID name? I need to keep track of the ID so that I can call the ID with a click function later on once data has been validated. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide example code?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.id`. 
Just like how you would use `.innerText`